# Multimedia Component update - The socket connection was aborted

Tags: web8.5

I got below error, when I create/update an existing multimedia Component in SDL Web 8.5.

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket
>   timeout was '00:00:59.9840000'.

[image]

Comment: how big is your image? I believe by default there's a 32MB limit. Bigger than that, you'll need to update the timeout settings

Comment: @Reboert: Image size is 7kb only.

Comment: Hi @SudhakarRao. We are seeing a similar issue on 8.5. Did you find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had the same problem as this and resolved it by adding the `maxBufferSize` attribute to the `StreamDownload_netTcpBinding` and `StreamUpload_netTcpBinding` bindings in the **%TRIDION_HOME%\bin\TcmServiceHost.exe.config** file.

After the change the configuration was as follows:

`<binding name="StreamDownload_netTcpBinding" maxBufferSize="524288" 
 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedResponse" sendTimeout="00:10:00"/>
<binding name="StreamUpload_netTcpBinding" maxBufferSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="StreamedRequest" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"/>`

This had the effect of increasing the buffer size from its default 65,536 bytes to 524,288 bytes (~500KB).

This problem only occurred when users were members of groups that did not have their membership scope set to **All Publications** and the problem appears to be due to the request header size.